# Why is the C preprocessor trying to parse quotes within a #if 0 block?

Tags: c-preprocessor

demo.c:

```
#if 0
What's the problem?
#endif
```

This produces (gcc)

```
demo.c:2:5: warning: missing terminating ' character
 What's the problem?
     ^
```

But this compiles:

```
#if 0
What{s the problem?
#endif
```

Why is the compiler trying to compile the apostrophe? I thought stuff within `#if 0 ... #endif` would be skipped-over. It's not as if the rest of the block's contents compiles.

What's happening?

Comment: If it didn't parse quotes, then it would be faked out by `printf("#endif");` The contents of the `#if 0` block must still be parseable or the preprocessor wouldn't know when to stop skipping.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't *parse* text inside a conditional include whose condition is false, but it does:

- Interpret trigraphs (deprecated, but still in the standard)
- Combine lines which end with a continuation character
- Replace comments with whitespace
- Divide the resulting text into preprocessing tokens
- Recognise preprocessing directives.

(See [§5.1.1.2 Translation Phases](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2) of the C standard for a detailed description.)

Since tokenisation precedes preprocessing, comments, character literals and string literals must be correctly terminated even inside conditionally included blocks which are clearly not included (`#if 0`).

Among other things, that means that you can put `#` inside comments and string literals without worrying about them being interpreted as preprocessor directives. (C doesn't have multiline string literals, but C++ does and its possible that some future version of C will follow suit.)

After the preprocessing directives are handled, the preprocessing tokens in the resulting stream are (individually) reinterpreted as program tokens, whitespace is discarded, consecutive character string literals are combined, and the stream of tokens is parsed.